# Generate an Hour Glass pattern

Tags: python, ascii-art

Here is my code for making an Hour Glass pattern with odd or even input using Python.  I think I could make it simpler.

Here's the output example:

[image: Expected Output]

And then, here is my code:

```
def evenGlassHour(target):
 jsp=1
 jtop=target
 jbot=2
 jbotspace=int(target/2)
 eventarget=int(target/2)
 temp=""
 for i in range(eventarget):
     for j in range(i):
         temp+=" "
     for jsp in range(jtop):
         temp+="@"
     jtop-=2
     temp+="\n"
 for i in range(eventarget-1):
     for j in range(jbotspace-2):
         temp+=" "
     for j in range(jbot+2):
         temp+="@"
     jbot+=2
     jbotspace-=1
     temp+="\n"

 print(temp)

def oddGlassHour(target):
 jsp=1
 jtop=target
 jbot=1
 jbotspace=int(target/2)
 oddtarget=int(target/2)
 temp=""
 for i in range(oddtarget):
     for j in range(i):
         temp+=" "
     for jsp in range(jtop):
         temp+="@"
     jtop-=2
     temp+="\n"
 for i in range(oddtarget+1):
     for j in range(jbotspace):
         temp+=" "
     for j in range(jbot):
         temp+="@"
     jbot+=2
     jbotspace-=1
     temp+="\n"

 print(temp)

target=int(input("Input : "))

if(target%2==0):
 evenGlassHour(target)
else:
 oddGlassHour(target)
```

And this is the result from my code:

```
 Input : 6
 @@@@@@
  @@@@
   @@
  @@@@
 @@@@@@

 Input : 7
 @@@@@@@
  @@@@@
   @@@
    @
   @@@
  @@@@@
 @@@@@@@
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: I've also edited to remove your request for Java code, as that's off-topic here; we simply *review* your code.  We might make concrete suggestions, but we don't write code to order!

Answer (score 16):

Read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it will give you directions on how to write Python code that look like Python code to other.

Other than that, the behaviour you're seeking is already implemented in `range`:

```
>>> a = range(7, 0, -2)
>>> list(a)
[7, 5, 3, 1]
```

You just need to reverse it to form the full hourglass:

```
>>> a = range(7, 0, -2)
>>> list(a) + list(reversed(a))
[7, 5, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5, 7]
```

And remove the repeated center:

```
>>> decreasing = range(7, 0, -2)
>>> increasing = reversed(decreasing)
>>> next(increasing)  # Remove duplicated center
>>> list(decreasing) + list(increasing)
[7, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Now you can make use of [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) instead of list concatenation and turn your function into a generator to separate computation from printing.

```
import itertools


def hourglass(size):
    decreasing = range(size, 0, -2)
    increasing = reversed(decreasing)
    next(increasing, None)  # Remove duplicated center
    for length in itertools.chain(decreasing, increasing):
        yield '{:^{}}'.format('@' * length, size)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(20):  # Test our function
        print('\n'.join(hourglass(i)), end='\n---\n')
```

Note that if you are using Python 3.6+ you can format the line using

```
yield f'{"@" * length:^{size}}'
```

instead which may be slightly more readable.